# Convert java.lang.object to int in Java

Tags: java

I have a method which returns a object of type `java.lang.object` and I want to convert it to `int`. I tried this:

```
oldComment.get("count");
```

return a `java.lang.object` and I want to convert it to int. I tried:

```
(Integer)oldComment.get("count");
Integer.valueOf(oldComment.get("count"));
Integer.parseInt(oldComment.get("count"));


con = Base.connection();
String query = "UPDATE COMMENT SET LIKES = ? WHERE POST_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setObject(1, (Integer.parseInt(oldComment.get("likes").toString())) + Integer.valueOf(rateComment.getCount()));
pst.setString(2, rateComment.getPost_id());
int k = pst.executeUpdate();
```

This is the code `(Integer.parseInt(oldComment.get("likes").toString()))` that is causing issue.

**Error Stacktrace:**

```
[qtp25844331-17] ERROR spark.http.matching.GeneralError -
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at com.soul.seeker.serviceImpl.CommentRatingServiceImpl.rateComment(CommentRatingServiceImpl.java:50)
        at com.soul.seeker.Application.lambda$main$12(Application.java:161)
        at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)
        at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
        at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
        at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

None of the above worked. How do I convert it?

Comment: What kind of object is it? What result do you expect if it is any kind of object? Suppose the object is an `Apple`, or a `House`, or whatever, then want integer value would you expect?

Comment: try Integer.parseInt(oldComment.get("name").toString())

Comment: It is of type `java.lang.object`

Comment: @NishadKAhamed Tried that also but didn't work

Comment: Please provide an example of one of your objects, and which `Integer` it should give, and why .

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: @NishadKAhamed updated question with stack trace

Comment: now it is clear that you are trying to convert an empty string to an Integer which is not possible. That is, oldComment.get("count") returns an empty string.

Comment: @NishadKAhamed No. When I print `oldComment.get("count") ` it is printing value

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't return `java.util.Object`, it's a very bad habit. If your value it's a Numeric, you should return `java.lang.Number`. If it's a String, you should return `java.lang.String`, etc.

If you don't have choice, you can convert it with this code :

```
// This method can throw NumberFormatException, catch it if you want
public Integer toInt(Object obj) {
    // Use intValue on a Number to improve performance
    if(obj instanceof Number) {
         return ((Number) obj).intValue();
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
}
```

EDIT : In your stacktrace, your program try to parse an empty String so it throws an `NumberFormatException`, you should catch it.

Comment: Its a method from other lib is returning. I don't have a choice but to try and convert it

Comment: Ok so you can use my method or just only a `Integer.parseInt(myObj)` but you should catch the `NumberFormatException` to manage the empty String (maybe return 0 in this case ?)

Comment: your method is similar is this line right? `(Integer.parseInt(oldComment.get("likes").toString())) `

Comment: I am not sure why it is throwing NFE when there is a value inside it

Comment: Yes the result is the same. In your stacktrace, the is no value : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Comment: But When I print `oldComment.get("count")` it is printing value

Comment: I am getting the `java.lang.object` from this library http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/